# Cannot view memory in stack with gdb

Tags: macos, gdb, reverse

I'm reversing a malware on Mac OS with gdb.
Then I try to view a local variable in stack,Gdb tells me:"Cannot access memory at address 0xbffffd58".Why?

```
(gdb) ni
0x000086cc in ?? ()
=> 0x000086cc:  85 c0   test   eax,eax
(gdb) i r
eax            0xbffffe0b   -1073742325
ecx            0xbffffd58   -1073742504
edx            0x190fc  102652
ebx            0x868e   34446
esp            0xbffffb10   0xbffffb10
ebp            0xbffffb58   0xbffffb58
esi            0x1  1
edi            0x17e9a  97946
eip            0x86cc   0x86cc
eflags         0x302    [ TF IF ]
cs             0x1b 27
ss             0x23 35
ds             0x23 35
es             0x23 35
fs             0x0  0
gs             0xf  15
(gdb) ni
0x000086ce in ?? ()
=> 0x000086ce:  74 e4   je     0x86b4
(gdb) ni
0x000086d0 in ?? ()
=> 0x000086d0:  80 38 2d    cmp    BYTE PTR [eax],0x2d
(gdb) x/3cb $eax
0xbffffe0b: Cannot access memory at address 0xbffffe0b
(gdb) ni
0x000086d3 in ?? ()
=> 0x000086d3:  75 df   jne    0x86b4
(gdb) ni
0x000086b4 in ?? ()
=> 0x000086b4:  bf ff ff ff ff  mov    edi,0xffffffff
(gdb)
```

Comment: I think OSX uses clang and lldb... You might try lldb

Answer (score 0):

Well,I think it is a bug in GDB:

```
(gdb) x/12i $pc-0x2a
       0x2473:  push   ebx
       0x2474:  call   0x2479
       0x2479:  pop    ebx
       0x247a:  sub    esp,0x34
       0x247d:  lea    edx,[ebp-0x19]
       0x2480:  mov    DWORD PTR [esp],edx
       0x2483:  mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x8],0x6
       0x248b:  lea    eax,[ebx+0x15a3e]
       0x2491:  mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],eax
       0x2495:  call   0xd900
       0x249a:  mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
    => 0x249d:  call   0x300b3
(gdb) x/10xb $eax
0xbffffcdf: Cannot access memory at address 0xbffffcdf
(gdb) x/1xw $esp
0xbffffcc0: 0xbffffcdf
(gdb) x/10xb 0xbffffcdf
0xbffffcdf: 0x2f    0x74    0x6d    0x70    0x00    0x05    0x7e    0x01
0xbffffce7: 0x00    0x27
(gdb) ni
0x000300b3 in ?? ()
=> 0x000300b3:  e8 48 42 de 8f  call   0x8fe14300
(gdb)
```

you see? Examine the same address twice,I get two different results.

And then,I input 'ni' command ,GDB doesn't stepover!

Gdb doesn't work well on Mac OS X?